# How to restrict normal user from creating and updating the books?

Tags: mysql, laravel, authentication, permissions

I implement user roles in a project in which books crud is implemented. I want that only admin can create,update and delete the books.
In my app.blade.php, I write the following code

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                            <!-- Authentication Links -->
                            @if (Auth::guest())
                            <li><a href="{{ url('/login') }}">Login</a></li>
                            <li><a href="{{ url('/register') }}">Register</a></li>
                            @else
                            @if(auth()->user()->hasRole('User'))
                                <li>
                                    <a href=""> User </a>
                                </li>
                            @endif
                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
                                    {{ Auth::user()->name }} <span class="caret"></span>
                                </a>

                                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="{{ url('/logout') }}"
                                           onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                                   document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                                            Logout
                                        </a>

                                        <form id="logout-form" action="{{ url('/logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
                                            {{ csrf_field() }}
                                        </form>
                                    </li>

                                </ul>
                            </li>

                            <li><a href="{{ url('/books/index') }}">Books</a></li>

                            @if(auth()->user()->hasRole('admin'))
                            <li><a href="{{ url('/categories/index') }}">Categories</a></li>
                            <li><a href="{{ url('/authors/index') }}">Authors</a></li>
                            <li><a href="{{ url('/publishers/index') }}">Publishers</a></li>
                            @endif
                            @endif
                        </ul>
                    </div>
```

When I login as user it only gives me books-view but when I put http://127.0.0.1:8000/books/create in browser, then it takes me to the create books view and book is created
[image]

But I want that If I logged-in as user then I could not create or update books.
How I can solve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
Try This code.
I think you are using auth() in blade Try AUth() in your if condition. 
@if(Auth()->user()->hasRole('admin'))
<li><a href="{{ url('/categories/index') }}">Categories</a></li>
<li><a href="{{ url('/authors/index') }}">Authors</a></li>
<li><a href="{{ url('/publishers/index') }}">Publishers</a></li>
@endif

Other Possibility is:

First add is_admin column in your migration

public function up()
{
Schema::create('user', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('email')->unique();
    $table->string('password');
    $table->boolean('is_admin')->default(0);
    $table->rememberToken();
    $table->timestamps();
});

Then you can check

@if($user->is_admin)

@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a middleware to protect your route from getting accessed by restricted user.
Create a middleware like this under middleware folder

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class CheckRole
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {

        if($request->user()->hasRole('admin'){
            return $next($request);
        }else{
            return abort(403,'Unauthorized Access');
        }
    }
}
```

And now put middleware in route middleware array in kernel file:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'signed' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,

        //Add the role middleware like this which we have just created.
        'roles' => \App\Http\Middleware\CheckRole::class,
    ];
```

And finally add your routes in group like this.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['roles', 'auth:web']], function ($router) {
     // Place your route here

});
```

And in the last don't forget to clear config cache by using this command:

```
php artisan cache:config
```

I hope it will help you